# How to localize a user and display a good version of my website

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I have a website in french. I'm using Express (nodeJS) in backend, JS in front and Handlebars for templating.
I have databases in MongoDB.

But how to localize my user ? If he is not in France, I want to show the site in english, with my english database.

I'm not sure i18 is a good solution because I'd like to change the template depending on the localization, not just translate the content.

Comment: Don't localize your users, let'em do it themselves. Ex. provide a drop-down for users to select a language if they want a different language.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in node.js

```
request.connection.remoteAddress
```

I found this on documentation :

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const ip = res.socket.remoteAddress;
  const port = res.socket.remotePort;
  res.end(`Your IP address is ${ip} and your source port is ${port}.`);
}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Country name of User using ip address

ip = request.getRemoteAddress()

http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=74.125.236.206

Comment: But to my IP, I'm getting XX

Comment: Thanks for checking with your ip address. Its a public api, it returns correct country code for most of the cases. If it returns XX then  the country name is UNKNOWN